# VBA:CreateObject("htmlfile") When run oWindow.execScript tips "access denied" In Other Computer

Tags: excel, vba

VBA:CreateObject("htmlfile") When run oWindow.execScript tips "access denied" In Other Computer

```
Set oDom = CreateObject("htmlfile")
Set oWindow = oDom.parentWindow
oDom.write "\<Script\>\</Script\>"

Set XMLHTTP = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")
url = "http://api.tushare.pro"
With XMLHTTP
    .Open "POST", url, False
    .setRequestHeader "Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    .setRequestHeader "content-type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    .setRequestHeader "connection", "keep-alive"
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Length", Len(arrJson)
    .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101   Firefox/104.0"
    .send (arrJson)
    SText = BytesToBstr(.responseBody, "utf-8")
    
End With

oWindow.execScript "var js = " & SText, "JavaScript"   '【When This Tips Access Denied】
n = oWindow.eval("js.data.items.length")
```

About 10 computers run well , only one can't run and tips "Access Denied"

Comment: How is this called? Is it in the event handler of a button?

Comment: What does "tips" mean? A popup window? Can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: Problem solved ：when I Uninstall updates for "Internet Explorer 11 " ，return to  "Internet Explorer 8"